# Monostable mode of ne555 is not working

Tags: 555, monostable

I am trying to connect a 555 timer in the monostable mode. Although it is a very simple circuit, I still for some reason can't make it work. I would appreciate it very much for your help in this regard. I have attached few images of the connection and oscilloscope captures (Fig 1, Fig2, schematic and fig 3,4).

I am using two different power sources, one connected as v1 using the red and black probes on the top side of fig 1 and another source with a DC voltage of 6V using the green and yellow jumper wires of the left side. The oscilloscope channel 1 is connected across the C1 capacitor using the black and white jumper cables of the right-hand side of fig 1.

When I turn on v1 source, the LED lights up immediately and stays like this the whole time, irrespective of +6V DC signal or 0V signal to the Trig pin. The capacitor C1 charges up to around 5.7 V and doesn't discharge unless I turn off all the supplies. If I turn off V1 and leave V2 connected (+6V) it drops down and remains at around 3V level.

I have checked the connection between the chip pins to all the wire terminals it seems to be fine, the LED, capacitor is also fine, and the polarized legs are properly connected. I have tried with different ICs but still the same result.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance. Looking forward to hearing from you.

The datasheet of the timer can be found [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ts555.pdf)

The SOIC to DIP adapter can be found [here](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/sparkfun-electronics/BOB-13655/5528943)

[image: Fig 1: Breadboard connection]

[image: Fig 2: Breadboard connection zoomed in]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3jLNX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Fig 3: Oscilloscope capture of voltage across C1 capacitor after turning on v1]

[image: Fig 4: Oscilloscope capture Vc1 and Vout after turning on v1]

Comment: You need also a decoupling capacitor (0.1-1 uF). 4.7 uf has a parasitic "paralleled" resistor too low or R1 is too high.

Comment: @Antonio51 Do you mean connecting decoupling capacitor at CV terminal (pin 5)? I already have a 47nF capacitor there. I tried replacing it with 1 uf and even 1 nf but nothing changed.

Comment: Capacitor between Vcc and Gnd.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot that can go wrong with this circuit, so a couple of quick test should find the problem.

First look at how you're triggering it. A 555 takes a low trigger. I would connect pin 2 to 12 V through a resistor, something like 10k. Then use something like a pushbutton switch (or just a jumper wire) to ground it momentarily. One problem I see is that it sounds like you're applying 6 V to the trigger pin before connecting the main power, that's a no-no, power should generally be applied before signals.

The next thing I would try is changing the capacitor from an electrolytic to something like a film cap, less than 1 uF. The electrolytic may not be able to charge high enough with the 1 Meg resistor due to it's leakage current. You could also try using a lower value resistor, but a CMOS 555 should be okay with 1 Meg.

A decoupling capacitor wouldn't hurt, but I've breadboarded plenty of 555 circuits without one and never had a problem. You can add one just to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

The THR pin must rise above 2/3 of the supply voltage to end the high output pulse which is about 8 V, higher than the 5.6 V which the timing capacitor is charging to. This might well be because the charging current through the 1 M resistor becomes equal to the leakage current through the capacitor as the voltage across the 1 M resister reduces which will halt the capacitor charging process.

You could try reducing the 1 M resistor to a value of 100 k and increasing the value of the 4.7 uF cap to 47 uF. This will keep the same time constant you currently have but will increase the value of the charging current to be greater than the leakage current enabling the cap to charge to a higher voltage.

A typical value for C2 would be 10 nF.

To make the trigger signal inactive it should rise to a voltage greater than 1/3 of Vdd = 4 V

Comment: First of all thanks to all of you for your inputs. I have tried the following things:
I added a 1uf capacitor. (+ve end to Vcc and -ve end to GND) Still it didn't change anything.

I always connect v1 first to the circuit and then apply 6v to the Trigger.

I changed the R1 to 100k and even 100 while keeping the same capacitor in the circuit. It doesnt help. The difference is just in case of 100k resistor the VC1 rises upto 11V and in case of 100 ohm it rises up to 12 V. But it doesn't discharge unless I turn off V1.

Comment: I noticed some weird things.

When the V1 is at is 12V and the V2 is 0 the voltage difference between Trigger pin and and GND is 1V. 

The Vout jumps up to 8.6V as soon as the 12 v supply is connected and doesnt change if I supply 6V or 0v in the trigger pin.

Even if I remove the C1 from the circuit while the 12V is being supplied nothing happens in Vout pin. 

The LED always remain to be turned on.

Comment: @minhazahmed Have you got a spare IC you could try in case the current one is damaged in some way? When trying a replacement IC ensure that you only apply voltages to the pins after the supply voltage is applied to Vdd and don't remove the supply voltage from Vdd whilst voltages are applied to the other pins.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Yesterday I tried it out with a spare chip. This time everything worked out perfectly. The problem was I suppose I might have mistakenly damaged the previous ICs by supplying Vtrig before Vcc. After the circuit was working i tested it out with different resistor and capacitor combinations (1k-1M resistors and 1uf -100uf capacitors) and decoupling capacitors. In every case the circuit was operating smoothly even without the decoupling capacitors.